# Forbid usage of defaults channel in Conda

Tags: python, conda

This one is getting a bit annoying for me: defaults channel is apparently paid and cannot be used commercially. Still, it is very difficult to get rid of it, as it keeps randomly re-appearing.

I made an environment, installing everything from `conda-forge`, and exported that environment to `environment.yml`. Now, I want this `environment.yml` to be shareable, even to colleagues who have no idea about differences between `conda-forge` and `defaults` channel. The top of my `environment.yml`:

```
name: py38     
channels:      
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
```

However, if I now copy this `environment.yml` somewhere else and run `conda env create -f environment.yml`, I see this:

```
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
```

Is there a way to specify NOT using `defaults` channel already from `environment.yml`? I know you can do it in `.condarc` when you already have environment but that is not really the point... I want to avoid accidentally usage of `defaults` directly from the `environment.yml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default channel can be forbidden by adding the `nodefaults` channel

```yaml
channel:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
```

[Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually)